# Deslizador JQuery UI en rango de 2 horas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, json, jquery-ui

JSON:

```
{
    "saturday":[
        {
            "start":"09:00",
            "stop":"10:00"
        }, 
        {
            "start":"12:00",
            "stop":"13:00"
        }
    ],"sunday":[
        {
            "start":"13:00",
            "stop":"15:00"
        }, 
        {
            "start":"19:00",
            "stop":"21:00"
        }
    ],
    "monday":[
        {
            "start":"15:00",
            "stop":"16:00"
        }
    ],
    "tuesday":[
        {
            "start":"19:00",
            "stop":"21:00"
        }
    ],
    "wednesday":[],
    "thursday":[],
    "friday":[
        {
            "start":"19:00",
            "stop":"21:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Esta es la vista:

Quiero mostrar los valores entre las 2 horas que aparecen, intervalos de 30 minutos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("json/datetime.json", function( data ) {

      //saturday
      if (data.saturday[0]!=null) {
        for(i in data.saturday)
        {

          if (i==0) {
            $('.available-time').append('\
                  <ul>\
                    <li>\
                      <div class="form-input-group">\
                        <div class="form--input-inner">\
                          <div class="choice">\
                            <div class="form-checkbox-group">\
                              <label for="saturday" class="form-checkbox-title">السبت</label>\
                              <input type="checkbox" id="saturday" name="saturday">\
                              <span></span>\
                            </div>\
                          </div>\
                        </div>\
                      </div>\
                    </li>\
                    <li>\
                      <div class="form-input-group available-range">\
                        <div class="form--input-inner">\
                          <div class="slider-range" id="saturday-range-'+i+'"></div>\
                          <span class="start-time">'+data.saturday[i].start+'</span>\
                          <span class="stop-time">'+data.saturday[i].stop+'</span>\
                        </div>\
                      </div>\
                    </li>\
                  </ul>');
            $("#saturday-range-"+i).slider({
              range: true,
              min: 0,
              max: 1440,
              step: 15,
              slide: function(e, ui) {
                var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
                var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);
                if(hours.toString().length == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
                if(minutes.toString().length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;

              }
            });
          }
          else {

            $('.available-time').append('\
                  <ul>\
                    <li>\
                      &nbsp\
                    </li>\
                    <li>\
                      <div class="form-input-group available-range">\
                        <div class="form--input-inner">\
                          <div class="slider-range" id="saturday-range-'+i+'"></div>\
                          <span class="start-time">'+data.saturday[i].start+'</span>\
                          <span class="stop-time">'+data.saturday[i].stop+'</span>\
                        </div>\
                      </div>\
                    </li>\
                  </ul>');
            $("#saturday-range-"+i).slider({
              range: true,
              min: 0,
              max: 1440,
              step: 15,
              slide: function(e, ui) {
                var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
                var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);
                if(hours.toString().length == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
                if(minutes.toString().length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;

              }
            });
          }
        }
        $('.available-time').append('<br>');
      }
```

(etc.)

El usuario debe seleccionar intervalos de mínimo 30 minutos de cada hora que quiera,como hago para obtener los valores para el formulario?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta ya que está en inglés y debería estar en español.

Comment: ¿Podrías listar cuáles son los valores que necesitás calcular? Sería más fácil que expliques cuáles son los que te están trayendo problemas, en vez de tener que descifrarlo de tu código.

Comment: ¿Tienen que ser tramos de 30 minutos exactos o eso es el mínimo?

Comment: los intervalos que me traigo del json pueden ser desde minimo 1 hora (pueden ser 3-4 horas), lo minimo que puede escojer el usuario es 1 hora, y luego a partir de ahi intervalos de 30 minutos.

Comment: luego que envie los datos puedo parsear los datos en el backend, por ejemplo puedo mandar lunes -> 12.30 - 13.00 y luego se convierten.

Comment: el problema es con los slider y como obtengo los datos del mismo cuando envio el form

Comment: No tiene sentido que utilices un slider "doble" (con dos valores) para eso. Si los intervalos siempre van a ser de 30 minutos, utiliza un slider simple.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar una técnica como la siguiente: Teniendo un número para la hora de inicio del slider `(data-time-start)` y la cantidad de horas que debe cubrir el mismo `(data-time-span)`, podrías crear una función para convertir los números a formato de hora. El formato para los números seguiría la pauta de los siguientes ejemplos:

`1.5` equivaldría a `01:30`
`4` equivaldría a `04:00`
`23.5` equivaldría a `23:30`

Después necesitarías una función a la cual le enviarías la hora de inicio y el rango de horas que se ha escogido y esta te devolvería la hora ya formateada para mostrar al usuario, por ejemplo si le enviamos como hora de inicio `6` y como rango `3.5` la función debería devolver `09:30`. De esta manera puedes implementar el slider usando números decimales y traducir estos números a formato de hora en cada interacción para poder mostrarlo al usuario.

Cuando vayas a enviar los datos puedes usar los números decimales y haces la conversión en el servidor o traduces los números decimales al formato de hora con la misma función creada y después los envías.

Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo para que puedas llevarte una idea del funcionamiento:

> NOTA: Para evitar que el usuario pueda escoger un tiempo menor de una hora, solo debes devolver `false` en la función que llama el evento `slide` cuando el valor sea menor que `1`. (Lo he situado en el ejemplo)

```js
var sld = $("#slider");
var start = +(sld.attr("data-time-start"));

//---Crear los atributos de hora
sld.attr("data-time-init", formatHour(start, 0));

//---Crear el slider
sld.slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: +sld.attr("data-time-span"),
    step: .5,
    value: 1,
    slide: updateSlider
});

//---Update Slider
function updateSlider (evt, ui) {

    if (ui.value < 1) { return false; }        

    updateHour(ui.value);

}

//---Update hour
function updateHour (value) {

    sld.attr("data-time-current", "+ " + value + (value === 1 ? " hora" : " horas") + " (" + formatHour(start, value) + ")" );
}

//---Format hour
function formatHour(init, span) {

    var total = init + span;
    var hour = Math.floor(total);
    var minutes = (total - hour) * 60;
  
    return "00".slice(0, - hour.toString().length) + hour + ":" + "00".slice(0, - minutes.toString().length) + minutes;

}

updateHour(1);
```

```css
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

#slider::before,
#slider::after {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

#slider::before {
    content: attr(data-time-init);
    left: -10px;
    -moz-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
}

#slider::after {
    content: attr(data-time-current);
    right: -10px;
    -moz-transform: translate(100%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, -50%);
    transform: translate(100%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="slider" data-time-start="9" data-time-span="5"></div>
</div>
```